# fetching data using useeffect returning empty list

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am trying to fetch data using useEffect and load the data before page reloads but useEffect is returning empty list and is rendering component two times first before getting data and then after getting data

```
function App() {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch data
    const dataFetch = async () => {
      const data = await (await fetch("http://localhost:8000/book/")).json();

      // set state when the data received
      setBooks(data["message"]);
    };

    dataFetch();
  }, []);
  console.log(books);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="data">
        {books.map((book) => (
          <Product key={book.isbn} book={book}></Product>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="buttonHolder"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And Output Of console.log is
[image: console image]

Comment: What's the exact question? What you expect here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected behavior. You are initializing the `books` property with an empty array, and react using this value for it's initial render. When `fetch` returns the data and you update the `books` property with `setBooks` hook. React re-renders the component due to the state value change.

Let me know if I'm missing something in your question.

If you want to add a visual indicator for this processing, you can add a loader. Something similar to below,

```
function App() {

  ...
  ...

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="data">
        {books.length > 0 ? books.map((book) => (
          <Product key={book.isbn} book={book}></Product>
        )) : 'Loading books'
        }
      </div>
      <div className="buttonHolder"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes Absolutely right but the fact that when i map on books i just don't see anything seems like while doing this react before fetching data is just using empty array, If there could be a way to wait before getting the data i thought async await would stop the flow but it doesn't seems to be happening here

Comment: I believe you want some visual indicator for this transition from empty list to populated one. I have updated the answer with pseudo code.